# How many scenes in the Chamber of Secrets book included Dobby?

Tags: harry-potter, dobby

My notes on the book make the strange claim that he only appears in exactly three scenes. I cannot believe that I ever cared to count, but my memory of the book agrees with this count. I can only recall:

1. Harry first encountering Dobby in his bedroom. I think there's a blink-and-you'll-miss it reference to Dobby before this, but I'm not sure.
2. Harry and Dobby talking in a hospital bed.
3. Dobby protecting Harry at the end.

Is my count accurate? Or are my notes as unreliable as I suspect?

Comment: The "blink and you'll miss it" is Harry thinking he sees two enormous green eyes like tennis balls in the hedge when he's in the garden.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your notes and memory appear to be correct. A text search for "Dobby" in the e-book version turns up active results for the following:

- Chapter Two "Dobby's Warning"
- Chapter Ten "The Rogue Bludger"
- Chapter Eighteen "Dobby's Reward"

Dobby is also passively referenced in the following chapters:

- Chapter Three "The Burrow"
- Chapter Four "At Flourish and Blott's"
- Chapter Eleven "The Dueling Club"
- Chapter Sixteen "The Chamber of Secrets"

Comment: If we're being more abstract he'd also have been present at King's Cross, and Quidditch game etc but I don't know if you'd really count those since you don't find out until later.